# Sharing Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, authorization, sharing

I am using Google Sheets as an online database for six users. It has buttons that run scripts mainly to hide/unhide sheets. People I share it with, tell me they require permission or authorization when they activate the button to run the script. I don't know how to grant permission. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script is attached to your spreadsheet and at some point, you authorized the script for your spreadsheet. now if you share that spreadsheet then all your people will need to do the same - authorize the script for a given spreadsheet for themselves (in other words, they need to allow running those scripts because all non-authorized scripts are by default disabled).

prompt them to enter script editor and press run button (triangle-shaped). a window will pop up with the question if they want to authorize those scripts. when they do they can use those scripts too.

if you are advanced script user you can set up an installable trigger for your spreadsheet to ease this process